# Path to bundle from AJAX

Tags: jquery, symfony

Basically I have a bundle in Symfony with `routing.yml`:

```
main_move:
    pattern:  /move/{direction}
    defaults: { _controller: MainBundle:Move:move }
```

And `javascript` file

```
$(".left_button").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
    url: '/move/1'
    }).done(function(){
    $(".button").css("width","1000px");
    });
});
```

Can I only put full path to that bundle or it can be like in twig: `{{ path(main_move)}}`(I have already tried that one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I did it like:

```
$(".move_button").click(function(){
    var path = $(this).attr("data-path");
    $.ajax({
    url: path
    }).done(function(){
    $(".button").hide();
    });
});
```

And in twig:

```
data-path="{{ path('main_move', { 'direction': 1 }) }}"
```

Answer (score 2):

Use JSRoutingBundle for this: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle